# HBase mass rows delete without Scan

Tags: java, hbase

I want to delete a lot of rows from HBase, in a greater mass of the amount of rows that I can scan with my resources. Is there any way of using the HBase Java API for deleting by these rows’ prefix, without performing any scan?

Unfortunately I have to use HBase 1.2, if that matters.

Comment: When you say 'with my resources' you mean you are concerned about your memory on the client or the server side? With the Scan class you should be able to set the maxSize property (in bytes) that should limit the scan (and therefore simply result in more scan round-trips to the server). Not sure if this is available in v1.2 but check the Scan properties in the Java API.

Comment: In the client side. I’m fine with the server working hard, that’s why I’d like to pass a scan + immediate delete, instead of holding the scan’s result data on the client side

Comment: I’m aware of the option of limiting, but it takes long time and feels unnecessary

Comment: You do have an option of sending a bunch of deletes in one call to the server in a BufferedMutator, but the problem is that you are trying to identify those deletes via a row prefix, rather than a list of exact row keys. I don't know of a way to do that without a scan, which is the only thing I'm aware of that can allow you a prefix-based search.